# Relationship between models, by name, fails on syncdb

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-syncdb

I have the 2 following models, and I'd like to link them with a ManyToMany relationship :

- www/hruser/models.py

  ```
  from django.db import models

  class HRuser(models.Model):
      """Custom user class."""
      email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, unique=True, db_index=True)
      is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
      is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      video = models.ManyToManyField('www.pandastream.models.Video', related_name='users')
  ```
- www/pandastream/models.py

  ```
  from django.db import models

  from www.hruser.models import HRuser


  class Video(models.Model):
      """Video object, really basic for now."""
      video_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, db_index=True)
      user = models.ForeignKey(HRuser, related_name='videos')
  ```

As you can see, they are in a different app, and Video also has a ForeignKey to HRuser.
To avoid a circular import in `www/hruser/models.py` I try to use a lazy relationship, as defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships) in the docs, but it raises an error on syncdb :

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
hruser.hruser: 'video' has an m2m relation with model www.pandastream.models.Video, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

So far, I have tried :

- to import my Video model in a python shell, which works
- to switch from mysql(5.6.10) to sqlite(3.7.12)
- to switch from Django 1.5 to Django 1.4
- to change the `HRuser.video` field to a simple ForeignKey field
- to look at the source of [`django.core.management.validation`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/validation.py#L140)

All of which didn't change anything to my problem, so either I do not understand the documentation correctly or the documentation is wrong, but either way, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to reference the target as a string, as explained in that docs link, is as `"appname.Model"`. So it should just be `"pandastream.Video"`.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I can't believe I have been missing that all along.